# how to identify which column has changed

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Is there an efficient method to identify which column has changed in a table in Oracle using a trigger? How to check if only one column (of interest) or all other columns also changed?

Answer (score 2):

As the post Alex Pole pointed in your comments states, you could use the UPDATING function.

But you can also develop different triggers for updating specific columns with "[BEFORE UPDATE OF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_trigger.htm#BABGDFBI)" clause, witch is the optimal option if there is no code to share among the actions for the involved columns.